# for loop error, for loop is not populating my array properly

Tags: javascript, for-loop, javascript-objects

I am doing regression analysis with javascript. I am trying to get the ui(the error value) from a stock price using the regression line. My regression line is in an array called line. My code is as follows...

```
function getUi(n, data, line){

var u = new Array(n);
for(j=0; j<n; j++){
    u[j] = parseInt(data['quote'][j]['Adj_Close']) - line[j];
}
return u;
```

Where n is the length of my regression, data is the array given to me from yahoo finance, and line is, as I mentioned before, is my regression line. I have used this same process to do basically all calculations so far(a for loop to populate an array which i then return the array) and they all work fine except this one. If I use n=200 it will return an array of 180. If use n=100 It will return an array of 88. This happens with n=50 and n=30, the only one that works correctly is n=15. The strangest part is to get my ui squared I use this code...

```
function getuisq(n, ui){

var uisq = new Array(n);
for(j=0; j<n; j++){
    uisq[j] = ui[j] * ui[j];
}
return uisq;
```

and it works perfectly. It uses the ui array that isn't fully populated and yet it returns a correct array that has the appropriate value(if n=100, uisq[89] would have the value of ui[89]*ui[89] but my returned array has no value for ui[89]). I've tried a whole bunch of stuff but it just dosen't seem to work. If you can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle demo with a sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why you need n. Try changing to

```
function getUi(data, line){

var u = new Array(line.length);
for(var j=0; j<line.length; j++){
u[j] = parseInt(data['quote'][j]['Adj_Close']) - line[j];
}
 return u;
}

function getuisq(ui){

var uisq = new Array(ui.length);
for(var j=0; j<ui.length; j++){
uisq[j] = ui[j] * ui[j];
}
return uisq;
}
```